# Counts by date and status with intermittent data

Tags: sql, sql-server

I would like to count the number of objects (lightbulbs, scheduled jobs, customer billing status) that are in a specific status by date.  However, the data is intermittent.  Objects may or may not have a row on a specific date.

Not a simple GROUP BY solution. The requirement for number of objects "in a specific status" depends on previous rows.

In the minimum problem to solve example below, on 03-01 a GROUP BY would result in "1 on and 1 off". On 03-02 only a single object is represented. A GROUP BY showing 03-02 results would be "1 on and 0 off".  The correct answer for total objects by status on 03-02 is "2 on and 1 off" because it must include the objects with rows on 03-01.

A minimum problem to solve is here

```
SET NOCOUNT ON
-->>-- minimum problem to solve  -- count by status for a specific day
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#d') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #d
CREATE TABLE #d (ndx SMALLINT IDENTITY(1,1), id TINYINT, dt DATE, status CHAR(10) )

INSERT INTO #d (id, dt, status)
VALUES
  ( 1, '20230301' , 'on'        )
, ( 3, '20230301' , 'off'       )
, ( 2, '20230302' , 'on'        )
, ( 3, '20230303' , 'off'       )
, ( 3, '20230305' , 'on'        )
, ( 1, '20230308' , 'off'       )
, ( 2, '20230308' , 'off'       )
, ( 1, '20230310' , 'off'       )
, ( 2, '20230311' , 'off'       )
, ( 1, '20230312' , 'off'       )
, ( 3, '20230312' , 'off'       )
, ( 2, '20230313' , 'on'        )
, ( 1, '20230314' , 'on'        )
, ( 3, '20230314' , 'off'       )
, ( 3, '20230316' , 'off'       )
, ( 2, '20230320' , 'on'        )
, ( 1, '20230321' , 'off'       )

SELECT * FROM #d d ORDER BY id, dt

IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#c') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #c
CREATE TABLE #c ( calendardt DATE )
INSERT INTO #c(calendardt)
VALUES
  ('2023-03-01 '), ('2023-03-02 '), ('2023-03-03 '), ('2023-03-04 '), ('2023-03-05 ')
, ('2023-03-06 '), ('2023-03-07 '), ('2023-03-08 '), ('2023-03-09 '), ('2023-03-10 ')
, ('2023-03-11 '), ('2023-03-12 '), ('2023-03-13 '), ('2023-03-14 '), ('2023-03-15 ')
, ('2023-03-16 '), ('2023-03-17 '), ('2023-03-18 '), ('2023-03-19 '), ('2023-03-20 ')
, ('2023-03-21 '), ('2023-03-22 '), ('2023-03-23 '), ('2023-03-24 '), ('2023-03-25 ')

SELECT * FROM #c UNION ALL SELECT * FROM #c ORDER BY calendardt

SELECT *
FROM #c c
LEFT JOIN #d d ON d.dt = c.calendardt
ORDER BY c.calendardt, d.id
```

The expected result should look like this

```
-->>-- expected result
calendardt  [status]    [count]
2023-03-01  on          1
2023-03-01  off         1
2023-03-02  on          2
2023-03-02  off         1
2023-03-03  on          2
2023-03-03  off         1
2023-03-04  on          2
2023-03-04  off         1
2023-03-05  on          3
2023-03-05  off         0
2023-03-06  on          3
2023-03-06  off         0
2023-03-07  on          3
2023-03-07  off         0
2023-03-08  on          1
2023-03-08  off         2
2023-03-09  on          1
2023-03-09  off         2
2023-03-10  on          1
2023-03-10  off         2
2023-03-11  on          1
2023-03-11  off         2
2023-03-12  on          1
2023-03-12  off         2
2023-03-13  on          0
2023-03-13  off         3
2023-03-14  on          0
2023-03-14  off         3
2023-03-15  on          0
2023-03-15  off         3
2023-03-16  on          0
2023-03-16  off         3
```

I do not have an attempt. I am able to track changes to the data on a per day basis. I can capture the first date the object entered a new status and calculate how long it has been in that status.  But I am not able calculate the totals by date and status.

Any help counting by date and status would be appreciated.

Comment: Sounds like a job for `GROUP BY`...

Comment: Also create an on/off table with 2 rows and cross join it and the calendar. Left join ...

Comment: How would GROUP BY work in this case?  As noted in the description, data rows do not exist for each object on each day.  For example, 03-02 should return totals of 2 on and 1 off.  But only a single row exists for 03-02.

Comment: The example shows a left join of the calendar with the data.  Note that many days do not have any rows joined.  But, I still need count totals by status for those days.

Comment: Lead(dt) per id to get the next/end date/dt of the status (if there is no next dt, get the maximum date of the calendar table) and join on the calendar table: `select c.calendardt, s.status, count(*)
from #c as c
cross apply (values('on'),('off')) as s(status)
left join 
(
select id, status, dt, lead(dt, 1, (select dateadd(day, 1, max(calendardt)) from #c)) over(partition by id order by dt) as edt
from #d
) as d on s.status = d.status and c.calendardt >= d.dt and c.calendardt < d.edt 
group by c.calendardt, s.status
order by c.calendardt, s.status desc`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
with changes as (
  select id, dt, status 
  from (select id, dt, status, 
               case when lag(status) over (partition by id order by dt)  = status 
               then 0 else 1 end chg 
        from #d) t
  where chg = 1),
cal as (
  select calendardt dt, id from #c cross join (select distinct id from #d) t),
joined as (
  select cal.dt, cal.id,
         last_value(status) ignore nulls 
         over (partition by cal.id order by cal.dt) status 
  from cal left join changes d on cal.dt = d.dt and d.id = cal.id)
select * --dt, stat_on, stat_off 
from joined pivot (count(id) for status in ([on], [off])) piv
order by dt
```

[SQL Server dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/INKurov9)

Initially I made solution in Oracle, dbfiddle is [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/6vKAkVdy). My knowledge of SQL Server is very limited and I can test it only in dbfiddle, but it returns expected values (until 13 April, but I think it should be 1 ON, because id=2 is ON).

The idea is to first eliminate rows which do not change anything (status off->off for example), then join with calendar and cross join with all ids. This way we have rows for each day and id. Then last_value fills missing data. And we can aggregate.

Comment: After reading my own answer I realised that first step is unnecessary: [dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/fV57peXe).

Comment: Thank you.  This looks promising.  Does not execute in sql server, but I can convert it.  Also, I will recheck the 'expected result' for 03-13 and beyond.  I did the 'expected result' by hand.  Could easily be off.  Thanks again.  I will update.

Comment: I upvoted your answer because it looks to have solved the puzzle.  Thank you.  Day off and have not converted to SQL Server yet.

Comment: Accepted as answer.  When I moved it to my company's antique version of SQL Server, it did not return the same results shown by dbfiddle.  But, in dbfiddle it does solve the puzzle.  And, I was able to steal enough of it to solve the puzzle in the antique SQL Server 2014 version.

Answer (score 0):

On/off table is missing

```
..

CREATE TABLE #on_off (status varchar(3));

INSERT INTO #on_off (status)
VALUES
  ('on'), ('off');

SELECT c.calendardt, c.status, count(d.id) n
FROM (
  select c.*, f.*
  from #c c
  cross join #on_off f
) c
LEFT JOIN #d d ON d.dt = c.calendardt and d.status = c.status
GROUP BY c.calendardt, c.status
ORDER BY c.calendardt, c.status
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/ZFZbAcRf)

Comment: Thank you for the effort.  Query above does not return expected values.  On 03-02, it returns 1 on and 1 off.    For 03-02, the correct answer as shown in 'expected result' section is 2 on and 1 off.  Also does not match expected result on other days.

Comment: @jim .. yes, it should count d.id . Corrected.

Comment: Again, thank you.  New version returns "1 on and 0 off".  Should return "2 on and 1 off".  It needs to aggregate the statuses from 03-01 along with the addition of a single row on 03-02.